# Creating a call and while looping over tibble columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I have write a function to transform character variables of a tibble to factors, do some manipulations and then transform the factors to characters back again (if they were characters in the first place). I would like to do that by creating a call.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(rlang)

N <- 100
d <- tibble(a = sample(LETTERS[1:4], N, replace = TRUE),
            b = sample(letters[20:23], N, replace = TRUE),
            x = round(rnorm(N, 100, 20), 1),
            y = as.numeric(sample(30:45, N, replace = TRUE)))

dplyr_xx <- function(d, ...) {
  call_vec <- map_chr(d, ~str_c("as.", class(.), sep = ""))
  d %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, as_factor) %>%
    # ... %>%
    imap_dfc(., ~ .x %>%
               exec(call_vec[.y])) # -> error
}
d %>%
  dplyr_xx(a, x, y)
```

How can I rectify the function above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?exec` help page, we see that the function to call should be provided as the first argument, followed by any additional arguments to that function.

In your case, `call_vec[.y]` is the function, `.x` is the argument. When you write

```
.x %>% exec(call_vec[.y])
```

it is equivalent to

```
exec(.x, call_vec[.y])
```

which has the wrong order of arguments (the function is now the second argument, not the first). Changing the order fixes the issue:

```
dplyr_xx <- function(d, ...) {
  call_vec <- map_chr(d, ~str_c("as.", class(.), sep = ""))
  d %>% mutate_if(is.character, as_factor) %>%
      ## ... %>%
      imap_dfc(., ~exec(call_vec[.y], .x))
}
d %>% dplyr_xx(a, x, y)
# # A tibble: 100 x 4
#    a     b         x     y
#    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A     t     150.     34
#  2 A     u     116.     32
#  3 C     w      81.2    30
# ...
```